# Tampermonkey script --After SWITCHING to a new tab from an old one, push an alert to the new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, alert, tampermonkey

I'm running a tampermonkey script on chrome.

What I want:

If a user starts off at an old tab, say google.com, and they go to another tab, I want to alert the user something.

Problem is, my alert currently only pops up on the google tab (THE OLD TAB), but now the user isn't on the google tab, they're on the other tab.

So they don't actually see the alert pop up, making it useless. Is there a way to pop the alert on the tab currently in focus (aka the new tab you navigated to from the google tab) or on all tabs in the browser window? Also, the solution will have to NOT include matching all possible url's on the internet.

IF the solution pops an alert on all tabs in the browser window, it should also be that clicking "okay" will dismiss all the alerts in each tab).

I've been using the window.onblur function to know whether the user switches tabs from the old tab to another, and it fires. Again, the problem is the alert pops up on the tab that the user does not see

```
        $(window).on('blur',function () {

                    alert("You switched tabs");
                    // do some stuff after tab was changed e.g.

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate between tabs with `GM_setValue()` and `GM_getValue()`. You can set your current url as value on blur and run a loop (with `setInterval()`) to get the value and look if it changed/alert based on its content.

It is not possible to dismiss alerts in other tabs.